# array how can I start a loop from the middle and make it end at the element before the start?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Newbie here!  I want to start the loop based on today (ex:"Thursday") and I want to make it stop on "Wednesday"...is that possible? Any help is appreciate! thanks

````
    let days = [
      "Sunday",
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday",
    ];
    let date = new Date();
    let today = date.getDay();
    let result = [];
    

    for (let i = today; i < days.length; i++) {
      result.push(days[i]);
    }

    return result[index];
  };```
````

Comment: To start with, I'd definitely research the modulus operator.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you want to do but if you want to start at Thursday and stop at Wednesday you need to reverse your for by decreasing i and if you want to stop before the end of the array you can use break in a condition to stop the loop.
Please be more clear of what you wnat and i can give you an example

Comment: Alternatively, you could loop from `today` - `days.length-1`, then again from `0` to `today-1`.

Comment: the double loop works! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, you could loop from `today` to `days.length`, then again from `0` to `today`.

```js
let days = [
      "Sunday",
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday",
    ];
    let date = new Date();
    let today = date.getDay();
    let result = [];
    

    for (let i = today; i < days.length; i++) {
      result.push(days[i]);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < today; i++) {
      result.push(days[i]);
    }

    console.log(result);
```

Comment: yes that's what I did a the end! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'm here because I had the same question. By God's grace, I literally just discovered a solution that can be done in a single `for` loop. It's so simple, I'm surprised I spent so long thinking about it.

## The Solution

```js
const array = [...Array(10)].map((_,i) => i); // Create an array with values from 0 to 9
const start = 4;

for (let i = start; i < array.length + start; i++) {
  console.log("Value: ", array[i % array.length]);
}
```

---

## The Explanation

If you already understand the solution above, then you don't need to keep reading. But if the solution above seemed a little confusing/odd, then hopefully this explanation will help you.

The following can be used to loop through elements from start to finish:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log("Value: ", array[i]);
}
```

We can also get the same result if we index the array using the [`remainder` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) (also called the modulo operator).

```js
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log("Value: ", array[i % array.length]);
}
```

This works because for any integer dividend, `N`, divided by a *larger* integer divisor, `M`, the remainder will *always* be `N`. For example, the remainder of 4/7 will always be 4. Similarly, the remainder of 0/7 will always be 0. So although we introduced the `remainder` operator into the loop, nothing changed.

Now, because of how math works, the remainder will *never* be larger than the divisor. For an integer divisor, `M`, the remainder `R` can only be in the range of 0 to M - 1. See the table below:

| Operation | Remainder |
| --- | --- |
| 0 / 3 | 0 |
| 1 / 3 | 1 |
| 2 / 3 | 2 |
| 3 / 3 | 0 |
| 4 / 3 | 1 |
| 5 / 3 | 2 |
| 6 / 3 | 0 |

Here, the divisor is 3. As we increment the dividend, the remainder loops from 0 to 3 - 1. And it's **this** mathematical phenomenon that we can use to loop over an array from *any* starting point.

If the following can be used to loop over an array from start to finish:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log("Value: ", array[i % array.length]);
}
```

Then -- because the `remainder` operator will "loop us back" to 0 when the dividend (in our case, the index, `i`) is large enough -- we can also use the following to start *anywhere within* the array and continue until we reach the previous item:

```js
for (let i = start; i < array.length + start; i++) {
  console.log("Value: ", array[i % array.length]);
}
```

All we had to do was shift the starting point of the loop. The `remainder` operator takes care of the rest. Hope this helps.